# how to import .txt contents into a line of code in python 2.7

Tags: numpy, python-2.7, matplotlib, pandas

I'm a Python newb, I tried searching if there were other similar questions but it doesn't seem that there are.  I'm really hoping my question isn't ridiculous, and why I didn't find others.

I have .txt file with 500 stock symbols that I have to include in my code to create an event matrix. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can somehow import the symbols into my line of code without having to type each individual symbol out.  I'm using Python out of terminal if that makes a difference.

Also Running on virtual machine on Ubuntu 12.04

The line of code looks like this.

Symbols = [""]

also somewhat unrelated to original question an example code shows this.

print '***'name'***' + "reading data"

Do the underlines represent something else and it just shows up like that in .py, it just seems it would run an error when trying it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Open the file, split it by delimiter (space? tab? newline?), and iterate over the collection of strings. Each one will be a stock symbol, so populate a list (or dictionary) with entries for each one.

Comment: Each symbol is in a new line so they're already split in the .txt file. You lost me after that, I have the .txt open in DrPython but working the code in the terminal. How do I populate a list with entries to each one than get it into the code line.

Comment: have you tried `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: @Poncho Don't think about 'code line'. Python programs do not edit themselves, they have a run time of variables and collections and dictionaries and all that good stuff, that doesn't affect the code itself whatsoever. You're making the list of stock symbols **at run time.**

Comment: My apologies .. @Andy Hayden I did not try that, how exactly would I go about using it. the name of the file is sp5002008.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes your file is of the form

```
AAPL
MSFT
IBM
```

and so on.  And your file is named `tickers.txt`.

To do it in `Pandas` do

```
import pandas as pd
tickers = pd.read_csv('tickers.txt', names=['Tickers'])
```

This will load the file into a dataframe.

To do it in `Numpy` do

```
import numpy as np
tickers = np.loadtxt('ticker.txt', dtype=str)
```

This will load the file into a numpy array.

The above solutions work, but it's probably overkill for a simple task like what you're doing.  I'd use vanilla python for this task.

```
with open('tickers.txt') as f:
    tickers = f.readlines()
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please click the checkmark so others know this problem is solved.